# Access a file located with find

Tags: shell, command-line, find, output

In many cases after I find a file using the `find` command I then want to open the file or cat it or maybe print it. How can I operate on the result from find? For example,

```
: find . -name "myfile.txt"
./docs/myfile.txt

: find . -name "myfile.txt" | less
```

does not work because it feeds the string "./docs/myfile.txt" to less, not the contents of the file at the specified path.

Comment: Do any of the 4 answers solve your problem? Don't forget to use the checkmark to indicate, if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @coffeeMug, this is the more up-to-date way to doing this as it is apparently faster:

```
find . -name "*.log" -exec ls -l '{}' +
```

I'll also point you to [CommandLineFu](http://commandlinefu.com/), which is always helpful with these things.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using find's `-exec` flag:

```
find . -name "*.log" -exec ls -l '{}' \;
```

In this example find searches for all log files in current directory and then 
list them using `ls -l`. In your case you should replace `ls` with `less`.
See the ACTION part of find man page here [find(1) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html).

Answer (score 2):

`less $(find . -name myfile.txt)`

```
less `find . -name myfile.txt`
```

The first is, I believe, both POSIX-compliant and nest-able.  The second, I believe, is more portable.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to automatically grab the output of the previous command (not under any usual environment). But if you manually select the output with the mouse, then you can run

```
less `xsel`
```

or, if the output contains spaces or wildcard characters and you aren't running zsh,

```
less "`xsel`"
```

If you don't mind running the command again, press <kbd>Up</kbd> then add `` less ` `` at the beginning of the line and `` ` `` at the end (or `` less "` `` at the beginning of the line and `` `" `` to cope with spaces in bash or ksh).